# Apache Thrift 0.9.1 generate golang code , param -r don't work

Tags: go, thrift

I use

```
`thrift-0.9.1 -r -gen go aaa.thrift`
```

to generate golang code

(note: aaa.thrfit include bbb.thrift which defined "Body" struct)

the param `-r` seems doesn't work, can't find "Body" struct in `ttypes.go`,

but when I try to use

```
`thrift-0.9.1 -r -gen java aaa.thrift`
```

has "Body.java",

how can I generate golang code which included files?
(note:from https://github.com/apache/thrift)

---

I know the reason, `namespace go service.demo` lead to the problem

Comment: Please try to find an http://sscce.org if the problem persists.

Comment: You mean, you used the same namespace in both IDLs? That's indeed something you shouldn't do with Thrift in general, because of the way code is generated for different languages. It may work (e.g. with Java) but I would not rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd thrift
$ cd trunk
$ cd tutorial
$ thrift -r -gen go tutorial.thrift
```

works perfectly for me.